# Android - Custom Grid Adapter getView() sets wrong position data when scrolled

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView with custom adapter as shown below. I also have set onClick Listener where adapter is set to gridView. onClick function shows correct position and data but the data I wanted to display in GridView is incorrent. I have 10 items in array list. When I scroll down, the second last grid item shows the values of first grid item. I googled a lot but unable to find a solution. Need Help. Thanks.

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<SupplicationMain> supplications;
Context context;

public CustomGridAdapter(List<SupplicationMain> supplications, Context c) {
    this.supplications = supplications;
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return supplications.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return supplications.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent,false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text2);
        textView.setText(supplications.get(position).getName());
        textView2.setText(""+supplications.get(position).getSubCategories().size()+" Groups");
    }

    convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, 300));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Setting the adapter :-

```
List<SupplicationMain> supplications = DataGenerator.getSupplications();
         CustomGridAdapter adapter = new CustomGridAdapter(supplications,getContext());
            gv.setAdapter(adapter);
            gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked "+supplications.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: In the `getView()` method, you need to move everything after the `inflater.inflate()` line outside of the `if` block, after it.

Comment: wow , thanks man , that was a quick fix.It works :)

Comment: No problem. The accepted answer on the linked duplicate explains why that was happening. Glad you got it working. Cheers!